# VC.net createprocess console redirect

Tags: visual-c++

I want to create a process to run a command line application. Then the app's console log can redirect to a file (textbox's text is better).

```
HANDLE hConsoleRedirect = CreateFile(
                         "C:\\zxd.txt",
                         GENERIC_WRITE,
                         FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                         NULL,
                         OPEN_ALWAYS,
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                         NULL);
```

I create the file handle

```
STARTUPINFO si;
si.hStdOutput = hConsoleRedirect;
```

but it dos not work

Comment: This isn't really enough info to go on. Some suggestions: make sure you zero-initialize the STARTUPINFO struct, perhaps with `STARTUPINFO si = {};` and also set `si.cb = sizeof(si);` and `si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;` and see what happens.

Comment: If you're using a really old version of Visual C++, you might need to do something else to zero the struct, like calling `ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));` instead. When you put VC.net in the title, I can't tell if that means you're using VS2002 or VS2003, or if you're using a recent version but trying to build with `/clr`. Apply more tags to the question to specify the VC++ version.

Comment: I have called the zeromemory funciton